# Include static resource with ltng:require as it is

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

Let us start with the problem description.

I am trying to incorporate `d3.js` into my Salesforce component. Here is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
>   throws at `https//path//:20:26`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560305/d3-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-document-of-undefined) is the solution provided and explained. The error happens because lightning changes the `.js` file content.

I checked it. And it turned out to be true. I compared the file I download as a static resource to Salesforce and the one which I am getting in the Google Chrome console. They were really different, the Salesforce added `"use strict"` and performed other tweaks.

So, I naturally come up with the question how could I prevent the file modification done by lightning in the `ltng:require` tag?

Comment: what is your d3 chart version.

Comment: @Himanshu, `3.5.17`.

Comment: this issue is with locker service so can you try D3 4.4.0 version

Comment: @Himanshu, it works with `5.4.0`.

Comment: so if it working what you need? as I said earlier this is because locker service restriction. either you need to use js strict compatible version or use lower api version of lightning component.

Comment: @Himanshu, why do not you want to propose it as an answer? And still there are may be cases when I want to use earlier versions

Comment: This is system restriction. You need to lower down the lightning component version to 39 or less to access component without locker service.